# Batch creating/updating intermediate pivot attributes in Laravel 9.x

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-9

I'm building a meal planner that automatically creates a shopping list, and one of the key things is being able to set the quantity of an ingredient on a recipe. I'm doing this by using intermediate values on my pivot between `Recipe -> Ingredients`. This is defined in my intermediate pivot model, IngredientRecipe, which stores a unit & quantity that the recipe needs.

```
Recipe -> IngredientRecipe(Quantity,Unit) -> Ingredient
```

I'm having an issue setting the quantity and unit for each ingredient. I know that I could loop and iterate through each one individually after they're created; however, that just feels wrong, and I'd instead do it in a single query.

I'm a bit stuck on how to proceed with this. I would have thought initializing a bunch of IngredientRecipe pivots with their values set and just saving them to the Recipe would be enough, but the pivot values aren't preserved. This is all built with Laravel 9.2 on PHP 8.1.

**Recipe.php**

```
...

public function ingredients(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredient::class)
        ->using(IngredientRecipe::class);
}
```

**IngredientRecipe.php**

```
...

protected $fillable = [
    'recipe_id',
    'ingredient_id',
    'quantity',
    'unit_id',
];

public function recipe(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Recipe::class);
}

public function ingredient(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Ingredient::class);
}

public function unit(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Unit::class);
}
```

**UpdateIngredientRecipe.php**

```
...

    return [
        'unit' => 'required|array',
        'quantity' => 'required|array',
        'unit.*' => 'integer|exists:units,id',
        'quantity.*' => 'numeric|digits_between:0,999',
    ];
```

**IngredientRecipeController.php**

```
...

public function update(Recipe $recipe, UpdateIngredientRecipe $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $pivots = collect($request->validated('quantity'))
        ->map(function (float $quantity, int $ingredient_id) use ($request, $recipe): IngredientRecipe {

            $payload = [
                'ingredient_id' => $ingredient_id,
                'recipe_id' => $recipe->id,
                'quantity' => $quantity,
                'unit_id' => (int) $request->validated('unit')[$ingredient_id],
            ];

            return IngredientRecipe::make($payload);
        });

    $recipe->ingredients()->attach($pivots->pluck('ingredient_id'), $pivots->first()->toArray());
    dd(__METHOD__, $recipe->fresh('ingredients')->ingredients);

    return redirect()->route('recipe.get', $recipe);
}
```

Comment: With your code I think you can just swap `IngredientRecipe::make($payload);` with `IngredientRecipe::create($payload);` and remove the `attach` line completely

Comment: Thanks for your input @apokryfos I was hoping to avoid this type of operation as it would execute a query for every single ingredient.

Answer (score 0):

So I've solved this by myself. Seems painfully obvious in retrospect but I hope this helps someone who gets stuck on a similar thing in future.

I'm now building an array of the pivot attributes keyed by the **Ingredient** ID

```php
    public function update(Recipe $recipe, UpdateIngredientRecipe $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $payload = [];
        $pivots = collect($request->validated('quantity'))
            ->each(function (float $quantity, int $ingredient_id) use ($request, $recipe, &$payload) {

                $payload[$ingredient_id] = [
                    'recipe_id' => $recipe->id,
                    'quantity' => $quantity,
                    'unit_id'  => (int) $request->validated('unit')[$ingredient_id],
                ];
            });

        dump($recipe->ingredients()->sync($payload));
        dd($recipe->fresh()->ingredients);

        return redirect()->route('recipe.get', $recipe);
    }
```

so in a sense what I'm doing now is:

```php
$ingredientsToSync = [
    $ingredient_id => [
        'recipe_id' => $recipe->id,
        'quantity' => $quantity,
        'unit_id'  => (int) $request->validated('unit')[$ingredient_id],
    ], 
    ... // other ingredients below
];

$recipe->ingredients()->sync($ingredientsToSync);
```

It's also worth noting that I needed to update my relationship definition in **Recipe** in order to get the pivot values

```php
    // Recipe.php
    ...
    public function ingredients(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredient::class)
            ->using(IngredientRecipe::class)
            ->withPivot(['quantity', 'unit_id']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be sufficient for your use case:

```
public function update(Recipe $recipe, UpdateIngredientRecipe $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $pivots = collect($request->validated('quantity'))
            ->map(function (float $quantity, int $ingredient_id) use ($request, $recipe): IngredientRecipe {

                return [
                    'ingredient_id' => $ingredient_id,
                    'recipe_id' => $recipe->id,
                    'quantity' => $quantity,
                    'unit_id'  => (int) $request->validated('unit')[$ingredient_id],
                ];
        });
        IngredientRecipe::createMany($pivots);

        return redirect()->route('recipe.get', $recipe);
    }
```

Since the relationship data is already in the pivot array you don't need to attach them as well. `createMany` may be able to mass insert rows and save on multiple db/server round-trips.